# How to inherit another class in the navigation drawer Fragment?

Tags: android, inheritance, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have a new android project with a navigation drawer. Now i want to add a new base class and inherit it in the navigation drawer fragment class. But it already extends Fragment. So how do I inherit the base class in the navigation drawer fragment?

Comment: Is your issue solved? Please don't forget to accept the answer which helped you most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple inheritance does not exit in Java. Essentially what you have to do is make the base class inherit from `Fragment` and then you can extend your navigation drawer `Fragment` from the base class.

```
public class BaseFragment extends Fragment {
    ...
}

public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends BaseFragment {
    ...
}
```